# Analog for C#'s Settings in Java?

Tags: java, jar, settings

I already know Java's [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). The only disadvantage of this class is that it seemingly needs to store the settings in an external file. As far as I know C#'s Settings class stores all data within the actual executable. **Is there a possibility to store readable and writable data within the executed jar file?**

Comment: *Is there a possibility to store readable and writable data within the executed jar file?* Yes, it is possible. But I *strongly* recommend you don't. A jar file is a kind of zip file, and modifying data in a zip file is tricky (and I think you'd then have to write a class-loader to reload it).

Comment: `java.util.prefs` is another option -- still not in the JAR file, but in some system-managed location (in Windows, this is the registry; on Linux I think it uses some dotfiles in the user's home directory).  There is a built-in export-to-XML facility for moving the settings between systems.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom is right. Though `java.util.prefs.Preferences` may also use an XML file under Windows too, which might be useful for restricted Windows accounts disallowing changes to the registry. A common practice is to use a `.myapp` folder in the home folder: `System.getProperty("user.home")`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I know that I'm able to open JAR files with WinRAR. Is it possible to treat JAR files as ZIP files in code, so that I'm able to append a file with serialized settings/data to the archive?

Comment: No. You can't "append" to a file in a LZW archive; that's not how they work. Basically, you could do it but you'll have to compress the entire file at once in a `ZipEntry` (in the Java API) or however you add the file to the archive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API for doing that.

Is it *possible* to locate the .jar file where a particular class resides, and modify it?  Yes, with some work.  But you shouldn't do it, because:

- The change may not be seen until the next time a Java Virtual Machine is started.
- It undermines security, such as signed jars.
- It makes per-user settings difficult or impossible.
- It inhibits future use of [Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/), since runtime .jar files are either web URLs or cached temporary files.

Application settings do not belong in the runtime binary.  You wouldn't try to do that in a C or C++ application, after all.

Writing to a file somewhere within the user's directory is really the best way to save application settings.  You don't have to use java.util.Properties;  if the data is not a flat structure, or even if it is, you may want to use [XMLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) and [XMLDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html).

If the settings are non-critical (for example, window position and size), you can store them using the [Preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) class.

Comment: In my particular case I'll be the only user and I want to have only one JAR file. I still tick this answer as correct, because it wonderfully explains the problems of storing user data within the executable :)